# Can't go inside of json results in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I am using typescript first time. I have made two pages, the detail page is getting all details of the pokemon. But when I want to go inside I can't go. Following is method I am setting up state pokemon. Interface

```
export interface IState {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  pokemon: [];
}
```

I am getting data and adding it in state by following code

```
  public componentDidMount(): void {
    axios
      .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.state.id}`)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ pokemon: data.data });
      });
  }
```

following is my json coming back

```
{
    "abilities": [
        {
            "ability": {
                "name": "static",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/9/"
            },
            "is_hidden": false,
            "slot": 1
        },
        {
            "ability": {
                "name": "lightning-rod",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/31/"
            },
            "is_hidden": true,
            "slot": 3
        }
    ],
    "base_experience": 112
}
```

I can easily access base_experience by using following codes inside component

```
Experience Index: {this.state.pokemon.base_experience}
```

But I want to access abilities and using following code but getting error

```
{this.state.pokemon['abilities'].map((ability)=>(
 <p>{ability['ability']['name']}</p>
))}
```

I also used following but it is also giving same error

```
{this.state.pokemon.abilities.map((ability)=>(
  <p>{ability['ability']['name']}</p>
))}
```

Also tried by adding type `ability: any` but still not working and also changed in `tsconfig.json` with `"noImplicitAny": false` but still no luck. following error I am receiving

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

But it is list when I do console it shows list.

I understand this is repeating question I have seen almost 10 answers but could not solve it. if I do `console.log(this.state.pokemon['abilities']` it prints whole array with name and url. But when I try to map it is not doing it.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined for `this.state.pokemon['abilities'].map` and same for `this.state.pokemon.abilities.map`

Comment: You've changed the type of "pokemon" to an array now. It is not an array, but an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because you're trying to access an undefined property and your initial state of pokemon is currently blank, try this way instead

```
{this.state.pokemon.abilities && this.state.pokemon.abilities.map((ability)=>(
  <p>{ability['ability']['name']}</p>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! awesome although I did that too but some how I may have issue with understanding and my condition was not correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've declared `pokemon` as `[]`. It should have type `any` (or preferably, define a type describing the format of the data).

The following program compiles and logs "static" and "lightning-rod" as expected:

```
interface IState {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  pokemon: any;
}

let data = {
    "abilities": [
        {
            "ability": {
                "name": "static",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/9/"
            },
            "is_hidden": false,
            "slot": 1
        },
        {
            "ability": {
                "name": "lightning-rod",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/31/"
            },
            "is_hidden": true,
            "slot": 3
        }
    ],
    "base_experience": 112
};

function foo(state: IState) {
    return state.pokemon.abilities.map((ability: any) => ability.ability.name);
}

console.log(foo({id : "x", url: "blah", pokemon: data}));
```

Comment: it was any too! but same issue even I used your code but still incorrect. but jersrej solve it. Thank you